# Extend python class in one file so it can be imported and used by class in another file

Tags: python, class, inheritance, extends

I have the following modules in python which I downloaded using pip.

```
mainmodule
    |
    |--utils
    |    |
    |    |--search_obj.py
    |
    |--search.py
```

The `search` looks like this,

```
import requests
from unidecode import unidecode

from .utils.search_obj import SearchObj


def search_text(text):
..............
..............
```

and `search_obj.py` looks like this,

```
class SearchObj(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id, tag):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.tag = tag

    def some functions():
...........
...........
```

So to execute it I do this,

```
mainmodule.search.search_text('testword')
```

It just returns me a SearchObj.

I want to print the name, id and tag.

If I go into the module and create a new function like this,

```
class SearchObj(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id, tag):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.tag = tag

    def print_stuff():
        return self.id, self.name, self.tag
```

Then try,

```
mainmodule.search.search_text('testword').print_stuff()
```

I can see the `name`, `id` and `tag`.

I don't want to go in and modify the function this way.

Is there a way I can import the module and just add this extra function so that the search file can access this new function?

I tried this,

```
class finder (SearchObj):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SearchObj, self)
    def print_stuff(self):
        return self.tag, self.name, self.id
```

But I keep getting an error, when I run this.

```
finder.search.search_text('testword').print_stuff()
```

This is the error,

```
AttributeError: type object 'finder' has no attribute 'search'
```

Comment: You added the tag `inheritance`. Did you consider using inheritance?

Comment: I tried but I can't get it to run, it just keeps saying the function is missing

Comment: hold on I will add the code I tried

Comment: I think your problem is not in extending `SearchObj`, but in getting `search_text` to *create* an instance of your new class.

Comment: what's the proper way to do it? I can't figure out how to extend it properly

Comment: You are probably better off just defining a regular function `print_stuff(obj: SearchObj) -> Tuple[str, str, str]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post says that this: `mainmodule.search.search_text('testword').print_stuff()` returns the id, name and tag so you can see it, so it follows that:

`s = mainmodule.search.search_text('testword')`

will return an instance of `SearchObj`.

Now you can do: `print(s.id)` to see the `id`, or modify that instance using: `s.name = 'new name'` etc.